# Can FB messenger video calls be intercepted?

Tags: tls, privacy, man-in-the-middle

My friend had a video call conversation through FB messenger. Both parties used malware free Android version 4.1. One used a personal wifi (WPA2 secured) and the other used 3g globe telecom data (LTE). What is the probability that someone could sniff or intercept?  Is Facebook recording the conversation?

Answer (score 1):

All the communications done over Facebook Messenger are encrypted but that does not mean that one cannot sniff the packets. One can easily sniff the packets but the bad guy won't get to know anything as everything will be encrypted (unless the encryption is broken).

As far as Facebook recording the conversation is concerned, it's a complete NO for that. Facebook only keeps the logs of the when the conversation happened, with whom and duration.

You can also read their Messenger policy for more info.

Comment: As long as they don't do end to end encryption, Facebook could potentially save the entire conversation, but it might be unlikely that they would lie about not doing that.

Comment: If you want to be toatlly sure that they are not capturing your conversations, you can see the following link to help you initiate end-to-end encryption in the Facebook Messenger [link] https://www.cnet.com/how-to/secret-conversation-how-to-enable-messengers-end-to-end-encryption/

Comment: How high is the probability of that video call to be intercepted or sniff?

Comment: @aemcam probability of intercepting a video call is very low as the hacker needs to accumulate large number of packets to get the conversation and it can be time consuming to decipher the packets also if they are encrypted. But if someone is hell bent on intercepting the call, nothing can stop him.

Comment: are there cases of video call interception done through fb messenger?

Comment: @aemcam I have not come across any such case.

Comment: What happen to the data of video calls after the conversation? Do they get stored somewhere?

Comment: @aemcam Some meta data related to the calls has to be kept for security reasons and for Logs too

Comment: So, is it safe to use fb messenger video calling feature? Do I have to worry about it?

Comment: @aemcam yeah its totally safe to use their services.

Comment: So, it's safe to use fb messenger but why are there video calls leaked online?

Comment: @aemcam sniffing packets while using a secured and encrypted service is very difficult and almost impossible for a novice.Most of the online leaked videos are due to compromised end user machines. Some one them are filled with trojans or RATs or any other monitoring and recording softwares.

Comment: I think most leaked are caused by recording conversation by the participants right? What are the signs that an android device is infected with such trojans and monitoring sofware?